# Pull word from sentence

Tags: php

is there a way to find a word in a sentence using PHP? We have a form and in the subject line we want to redirect someone if they use the words delivery, deliver, or delivered. Can this be done and how would it be? thank you for any help on this subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if ( preg_match('/deliver(?:y|ed)?/i', $subject) )
{
  // Redirect
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strpos` function to search for a string inside another string. If the string is not found `false` will be returned, and you know that your string was not found.

Comment: Note that when using `strpos`, you shoud use condition like `if(strpos(...) !== false)` or else the statement will always return true. (if the sentence begins with the word, the position is 0 which evaluates to false)

Answer (score 1):

another method:

```
if (stristr($sentence,"deliver")) {
header('location: somepage.php');
}
```

But I would use preg_match as expressed before.

Answer (score 0):

One method of many:

```
if (preg_match('/deliver(y|ed)?/', $string)) {
    // yes, $string contained 'deliver', 'delivery' or 'delivered'
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for "deliver". You need to add a question mark (?) after (y|ed). I would also add the "i" modifier just in case the subject isn't all in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
<?php
if (strpos($string, "deliver")) {
   header("Location: somepage.php");

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. to extract all words, simple explode the string using a whitespace characters
2. to check a particular word either use the simple strpos() function or a regular expression pattern matching

   `preg_match("/(?:^|\s+)deliver(y|ed)?(?:$|\s+)/i")`

   The above expression checks whitespace character or beginning of string, similary whitespace character or end of string